TextInput Selection Jumps to End When Pressing Return Key
I'm working on an app that uses multiple TextInput components to mimic the behavior of a TextArea. Since I can't use multiline, I'm using onSubmitEditing to detect when the return key is pressed.
Here's the current setup of my TextInput component:
<TextInput
  placeholder={index === 0 && lines.length === 1 ? "Skriv her ..." : ""}
  style={[styles.contentInput, { color: textColor }]}
  value={line.content}
  onChangeText={(text) => {
    const updatedLines = [...lines];
    updatedLines[index].content = text;
    if (text.trim() === "") {
      updatedLines[index].count = 1;
    }
    setLines(updatedLines);
  }}
  onFocus={() => setFocusedContentIndex(index)}
  onBlur={() => handleContentBlur(index)}
  ref={(ref) => (inputRefs.current[index] = ref)}
  onSubmitEditing={() => handleSubmitEditing(index)}
  onKeyPress={(event) => handleKeyPress(event, index)}
  onSelectionChange={(event) => handleSelectionChange(event, index)}
  blurOnSubmit={false}
/>

When I make a selection and press the return key, the selection is automatically moved to the end of the word before handleSubmitEditing is called. This does not occur if the selection is at least one character long.
Here's the handleSelectionChange function:
  const handleSelectionChange = (event, index) => {
    console.log("Selection changed", event.nativeEvent.selection);
    const newSelection = event?.nativeEvent?.selection;
    if (newSelection) {
      setSelection((prevSelection) => ({
        ...prevSelection,
        [index]: newSelection
      }));
    }
  };



Here is the logs showing the order of the calls.
 LOG  Selection changed {"end": 0, "start": 0}
 LOG  Selection changed {"end": 4, "start": 4}
 LOG  handleSubmitEditing called

The word length is 4, and I was at the start of the word when pressing enter. This only happens when the selection length is zero, in other words if i have made a selection of at least one character it works as expected..
I have also checked that no other code is interfering with the selection.
How can I prevent the selection from jumping to the end of the word when the return key is pressed? Has anyone faced a similar issue or have insights on how to handle this?
This issue is blocking my progress, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Why can you not use multiline?
